# .htaccess Force SSL (HTTPS) On all pages besides a few

Tags: .htaccess, https

Ok, so i need to forward all traffic through `HTTPS` besides on ONE specific page. Here is my current `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

Options -Indexes
```

So basically i need to forward all traffic through `HTTPS` BESIDES my `/r.php` & `/l.php` & `/c.php` page, can this be done? I tried doing some research but haven't found too much.

EDIT:
Would this work?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/r.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/c.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/l.php$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes this can be done. Answer will appear shortly....

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want your `r.php` to be on HTTPS?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois i released a project awhile ago that downloads data from my website via a socket... This socket downloads via HTTP so when i changed to HTTPS people can not use my project..

Comment: Maybe you should update your project to support HTTPS.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois well it is used by a few hundred people so i do not want to inconvenience anyone and force them to re-download

Comment: It's an inconvenience to me when someone says he doesn't want his project to support secure connections just because it's a bother to download the update. It may be a nuisance, but that's not an excuse for not supporting secure connections. You don't wanna hear the same from your bank.

Comment: Yes that edit would work, but ***IT IS HIGHLY RECOMMENDED TO USE SECURE CONNECTION IF IT IS AVAILABLE TO YOU*** It protects your server as much as it protects your visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***IT IS HIGHLY RECOMMENDED TO USE A SECURE CONNECTION IF IT IS AVAILABLE TO YOU***

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#Add slash(es) before special characters to escape them as literals
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/r\.php$ 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

What this does is check if your HTTPS flag is set on the server, if it is *not* set, *and the page is not `/r.php`* then redirects the page to the secure HTTPS equivalant.

> EDIT: The `/r.php` entity needs to have the `/` and `.` escaped by having these characters preceeded by backslashes `\`.

The `RewriteCond` line "escapes" the `/r.php` page reference from the Secure connection flag check, it is better to use the proper server flag as detailed here, rather than manual port requests because secure/insecure standard hypertext protocol ports can be **ANY** port on a server, and it is only convention (and not at all required) that TLS/HTTP ports are 443/80 etc.

Comment: Please edit your question, it's very hard to understand code in comments. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that would

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project. @C0d1ng

Comment: The regexpr is wrong. it should be !^/r\.php$ to avoid matching r_php for example (I can't edit to fix only one char, 6 minimum, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new RewriteRule above your `RewriteCond` telling apache to process it as is and not applying any more RewriteRules (the `L` says, stop after matching this rule, `(r|c|l)` is a regular expression for matching `r` OR `c` OR `l`).

```
RewriteRule ^/?(r|c|l)\.php$ - [L]
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule for more information.